# Once I have the access_token, how do I get the associated user_id server side?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I know I can request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

But 'me' which refers to the 'active user' which presumably is the user logged on to facebook on this machine which would be the server, I need the facebook user at the clients end user_id so my server can make requests to the GraphAPI about that user using the format:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the SDK's I found they parse the user_id from the access token:

```
        /*
         * access_token:
         *   1249203702|2.h1MTNeLqcLqw__.86400.129394400-605430316|-WE1iH_CV-afTgyhDPc
         *                                               |_______|
         *                                                   |
         *                                                user id
         */
```

**BUT** one shouldnt have to do this as instead of requesting the token your app should redirect them to the landing page following which facebook will re POST the signed_request with the access_token and user_id. The facebook documentation on authorisation (it seems to have since been updated) wrongly told ones app to request token but that is only applicable for websites not apps. I find it annoying how the facebook docs keep telling one how simple it is yet they fail to simply explain it and get wrong anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the fundamentals of the user authentication concept which is not only related to Facebook.

Let us assume that two users **A** & **B** visited `domain.com/fb_profile.php`, which contains (the [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) file from the PHP-SDK):

```
<?php

require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APPLICATION_ID',
  'secret' => 'APPLICATION_SECRET',
  'cookie' => true,
));


$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

// rest of code
```

They both logged in successfully, and the page reloaded. What happened now is that we have a valid session for *both* users!
And when the `fb_profile.php` is requested from the user **A** (*client*) the `$facebook->api('/me');` will be holding the "active user" details *from that specific request (client)*! and your machine (*the server*) will be holding the sessions for ***all*** the logged in users!

So each time `fb_profile.php` is requested from a *client* with a valid session, the result of executing `$facebook->api('/me');` will be related to that *specific* session from that *specific* client!

So what have you said here (in **bold**) is wrong:

> But 'me' which refers to the 'active
>   user' which presumably is the user
>   logged on to facebook on this machine
>   **which would be the server**

And by the way, when you have a valid session both:

```
$facebook->api('/me');
```

And:

```
$facebook->api('/USER_ID');
```

Will return the same info (*of course the `USER_ID` is the id of the user logged in on the client-side*).

Comment: I see I have to establish a session - I understand how it works with sessions,  I am not using a Facebook SDK or PHP so it was not obvious to me. At a low level in my case I guess that would mean responding to the oauth request from facebook before closing the HTTP connection it came in on as I am not using cookies.